# Switch elements position with CSS3?

Tags: css

With CSS3, is it possible to switch 2 elements position? I think I remember someone showing me this with items in a list but I can't seem to find the style by googeling it.

The reason I need this is im mobile optimising a site with media queries. On mobile devices my site has a 1 column layout, and currently blog images appear before the blog titles. I want these the other way around and I can't currently change the source order in the html.

Thanks

Comment: I guess it's not possible or at least not easy in CSS.
But maybe you can use the `float` property on one element to cause that element to shift before or after the other element. But that depends on the layout of that particular webpage.
To swap the contents of those element, you definitely need JavaScript or PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Using your media query to trigger this, you'd just set the position of the elements where you want them using any positioning property that works, including floats. But without the markup, I can't guess at what you have.